# How to export photos from Insta360 Studio?

Tags: photo-editing, 360-panorama

I've opened a 360 photo I've taken with Insta360 Studio, set it up as a little planet shot & got it ready to export, but when I click the export / screenshot button to save my little planet image as a JPG, I pick the location to save it and it simply does nothing. Some times it says "Screenshot failed" but other times it does nothing.

There's no images written to the directory I chose & I'm not sure there are logs anywhere else I can interrogate. Should this just work? Or is there some crucial step I'm missing? I'm trying to follow along with [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRoC_PiiV4E) but for me the image just doesn't save.

Comment: I have the same problem, anyaone can help?

Comment: What directory are you saving to?

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version of the application? Did you try restarting the application?